# Debugging exited in iphone simulator but working in device

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios-simulator

I am trying to debug an application in simulator, the debug process is exited saying the

`dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  Referenced from: /Users/stellentmac2/Documents/ProjectName Apr 22/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName
  Reason: image not found`

To delete and replace the old image , i didnt find which the debugger has not referencing.

But, the app is debugging well in the device.

I also tried clean all targets,, quitting simulator and started again, but didnt worked.

Please anyone help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging is working fine now, when I close the xcode and simulator and restarted the mac.. don't why it happened previously, but now it gets solved after restarting..

Answer (score 0):

you check the project folder .May be you forgot to delete image from there

Comment: i have removed build folder and tried too, it didnt worked, if an image is deleted, it cant work in the device na.., but debugging is working in device..

Comment: it works fine in device na means now it is ok . you can tap the icon on simulator for 3 second and delete it from there , clean al trget and remove from documnt directry if teher is anything..